# JSON value to django_enumfield value

Tags: python, json, django, enums

I used `django_enumfield` in my Django REST project.

I defined my enum in this way:

```
class UserGenderType(enum.Enum):
    UNDEFINED = 0
    MALE = 1
    FEMALE = 2

    labels = {
        MALE: 'Male',
        FEMALE: 'Female',
        UNDEFINED: 'Undefined'
    }
```

In my model I have:

```
gender = enum.EnumField(UserGenderType, default=UserGenderType.UNDEFINED)
```

I would to use the label enum in JSON for example:

```
"gender":"Male"
```

but, how can I transform JSON value/string into my UserGenderType enum?

Answer (score 1):

So you want to look up the dictionary's key by its value like so:

```
In [1]: UserGenderType.labels.keys()[UserGenderType.labels.values().index('Male')]                                                                            
Out[1]: 1
```